# Java Multithreaded Socket Server hangs after getting ~ 50 simultaneous Connections

Tags: java, sockets

So basically the problem is described in the title.
The server works in the following way:

- Listens to a new connection
- Once connection is requested - adds the request to the Q,
- Continues listening to a new connection
- Separate process takes care of a Q and spawns a new thread to deal with the clients' requests.

The server code is similar to [this tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-multithreaded-servers/multithreaded-server.html) (everything is in try / catch, unfortunately I cant show the source-code - company policy)

It seems to work very well, until the number of clients exceeds ~ 50, Then it just hangs with no exceptions / warnings / etc. There is a cpu thread limit of 32k, no limits on the number of open files / open sockets / etc. OS = CentOS 5.5 (same seems to happen in ubuntu tho). The server logs data to MySQL using ODBC. Separate stress tests of both showed that I can have up to 32k java processes (limited by /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max ) and MySQL can perform up to 20k simple operations / second, so Im assuming the problem is with the sockets.

So the question really is:

- What is the limiting factor in socket connections and how can I make it bigger?
- OR am I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: Hi, what did you mean when you said "actually its a problem with java.io.DataInputStream.readByte() - its getting an unexpected EOF and hangs then" - can you show what the problem was and what you did to fix it?

Comment: @phobus Hi, the problem was that the client stopped sending the string it was meant to send (connection problems / delays, etc) and the server was waiting for the rest of the string (until defined EOF was found) to perform some operation. I didnt fix it, I rather changed it, so it will only read what it has found, e.g. :
`int available = streamIn.available();
while (available > 0)

 {
  byte cr = streamIn.readByte();
  if (cr == EOF)
  {
   break;
  }
  myString += (char) cr;
  available --;
 }`

Comment: Sorry, it doesnt look too good in the comment section, but its readable and I hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The chances are that you have induced a deadlock somewhere in the code. The key indicator here is if by 'hang' you mean the CPU usage of the server drops to nothing and no futher activity is seen in the server.

When the server hangs run [jdk tool: jstack](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jstack.html) against it's process. This should show you what is waiting on what lock. Also in the tool kit is [jvisualvm](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html) and if on a unix box a simple `kill -3 pid` will do a thread dump to stderr.

With out the code or at least a reproducable sample I'm afraid I can't help much more. One thing you might want to look at is using [jetty](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/) as your embedded server instead of a hand roled one, they have already been through the deadlock/threading pain so you don't have to.

Comment: +1 Also, it would help if he at least told what's the CPU utilization when the server "hangs". If it's low, it most certainly would be a deadlock. The jstack tip is priceless.

Comment: Thanks, deadlock seems to be it :) Will have to spend some time figuring this one out.

Comment: any form of multithreaded programming is not for the faint hearted. recommended (almost required) reading is http://www.javaconcurrencyinpractice.com

Comment: yah, thanks, actually its a problem with java.io.DataInputStream.readByte() - its getting an unexpected EOF and hangs then

Answer (score 0):

Don´t know if this will help you and if your are using it, but try to run your socket server with java switch "**-server**",this will select the Java HotSpot Server VM.The -server turns on the optimizing JIT along with a few other "server-class" settings. Generally you get the best performance out of this setting. The default VM is -client.

Also check your other params, so your socket server don´t run with minimal resources
Have a nice day

Comment: The params are default, so it takes up as much as it wants too... there should be enough to facilitate it. Added -server switch, but thats not the problem.